# NSString completePathIntoString method issues

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, foundation

in my command line program I used these codes to get array of files begin with "r" in folder "/Users/me/Demo"

```
NSString *partialPath = @"~/Demo/r";
NSString *longestCompletion;
NSArray *outputArray;
NSUInteger allMatches = [partialPath completePathIntoString:&longestCompletion
                                              caseSensitive:NO
                                           matchesIntoArray:&outputArray
                                                filterTypes:NULL];
```

when I run my program inside Xcode it returns nothing But I found out if I run exec file via Finder it works correctly!! , why this happened and do I need something to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xcode isn't expanding the tilde correctly. I've run your code and got the same result as you did. However, when I replaced the tilde in `partialPath` with an absolute path, Xcode printed  the contents of the directory as expected.

If you don't want to hardcode the user's name in the path (perhaps you are trying to list the contents of a directory common to many machines), you could use the `NSString` method `-stringByExpandingTildeInPath`. If you call `[partialPath stringByExpandingTildeInPath];` immediately after you initialize `partialPath` you will get the result you want.

As to why there is a difference - expanding tildes is something handled by the command line shell. I presume that underlyingly Finder is using the shell's built in functionality when it runs your program, so the path is expanded correctly. Xcode doesn't have this automatically, so you need extra code to make it work there.

Comment: yeah I used `stringByStandadizingPath` and the problem solved as well.